# Sonarlint doesn't bring "Managed Binary Analysis rules" to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sonarlint

On the sonarqube server (Version 5.4) I have created a new quality profile for C# and I have enabled some rules like "CA1001: Types that own disposable fields should be disposable".
I have defined this new profile as default and I have associated the quality profile to the only project I have on the sonarqube server.
I have installed sonarlint extension version 2.1 on my Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.
I can connect to my sonarqube server and I have clicked on bind.

A new ruleset has been configure for every project in my solution.

My issue is that rules CAXXXX (ex: "CA1001: Types that own disposable fields should be disposable") configured on my quality profile are not configured in Visual Studio.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not missing anything, you're just hitting a known limitation: [SVS-64](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SVS-64) - *Connected Experience doesn't sync FxCop rules* .

Long story short (quoting the [related discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/GFYTu2Kky9Q)):

> The first release of the connected experience only works with Roslyn-based analyzers